# Why doesn't this for loop condition work?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, indexing, conditional-statements

Trying to output the value of a component of beta if its index is a multiple of 3.
I have the conditions set in the for loop but it's only printing the component at index 0. Isn't this allowed in the for loop condition? Do I really need to use an if statement inside the loop?

Thanks.

```
double beta[20] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

for (int index = 0; index < 20 && index % 3 == 0; index++)
    cout << beta[index] << endl;
```

Comment: "index < 20 && index % 3 == 0" is true when index == 0 but false when index == 1 and then the loop stops

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is about the `index` not the value at that `index`. (`[...]if its index is a multiple of 3[...]`)

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index < 20 ; index+=3) {  
        cout << beta[index] << endl;  
}`

Answer (score 2):

The loop stops the moment the condition is false. For `index == 1`, the condition is false.

If you want a loop that skips iterations, use an `if` in the loop body.

But for this simple case, it would be better to just increase `index` by 3 on every iteration instead.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for your loop is: `index < 20 && index % 3 == 0`
This condition is false at `index = 1`, so the loop stops.
To make this work, split the condition into two parts. Put one if `for` and one in `if`. Following is the code:

```
double beta[20] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

for (int index = 0; index < 20 ; index++){      // First condition
    if (index % 3 == 0){                        // Second condition
        cout << beta[index] << endl;
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I figured 0 % 3 is also 0 and I need to exclude it. I modified it a bit. Works like a charm now. Thanks.

 for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) 
 {     
  if (index % 3 == 0 && index != 0)                        
   cout << beta[index] << endl;  
 }

Comment: @Cornel accept the answer, if useful. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to calculate the `1 mod 3` it will equal *1* since that the 2nd condition will be false so program will  execute the body when  `index = 0`  only (`remainder = 0 here`) after that starts from 1 you will never enter the for loop body. Hope that helps.

Comment: Writing an answer completely in bold does not make it more readable, important or correct.

Answer (score 0):

What about this short answer doing everything in the for loop condition?

```
for (int index = 0; ((index % 3) == 0 || (index++ && index++)) && index < 20 ; index++)
    cout << beta[index] << endl;
```

Don't forget that we place `index < 20` at the end of the condition.

Comment: Not everything that works is a good idea. This is for sure a creative idea, but nothing that should be written in production code, because it is horrible for code review and maintainability.